# Linux Standard For Deploying Java "Side By Side" and Tools?

Tags: linux, archlinux, java

**Problem:**

For Developers that work on many different platforms and need to do regression testing on different versions of Java, the Android NDK, OpenGL, etc, there are often issues trying to install multiple versions of the JRE and JDK.

It is common to manually deploy/extract many versions of the NDK, JDK, JRE, and J2EE environments in linux, (archlinux).  However, automated installation packages are not-standardized in how/where they place the SDKs, and JREs, and there are often collisions reported during installations.

**Question:**

1. Is there a "standard" method described, provided by Oracle, (Sun), or any others that has been adopted, (for example, the best practices for setting up the proxies/shims, symlinks, etc?
2. Are there any common GUI tools, scripts, (like archlinux-java), that will let me "Switch" the Active Java environment?  (pointing symlinks in different directions, etc)?
3. Is there a tool that allows users to click "Add New Java Platform" and lets them specify JRE and JDK paths separately, (like, update 8_u34, and 8_u49, separately).

**Notes:**

archlinux-java only supports openjdk and java-8-oracle, but not the past versions of oracle java, (6, or 7), (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/java#Switching_between_JVM)

Hopefully, this "one tool" to proxy/shim for all of the different java versions would be updated in updates.

By manually installing the different java versions, its a given that this will break updates, but that is kind of the point--to test on different, older, and non-updated versions.

In this scenario, there are anywhere from 2 to 6 or so deployments on a machine.

What ends up happening is that /opt is used (sometimes), and usr/lib/jvm, and even other folders get pulled in with other installations.

It is preferable to have all of the deployments in one tree under "opt" or even "lib" so that its easier to change scripts/variables.

Thank you for your thoughts!

Comment: You could use [Chef](http://www.getchef.com/) and [Docker](http://docker.io) to create isolated environments for testing your apps with different versions of JDK, NDK, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Package [java-common](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=java-common) also provides a utility script **archlinux-java** that can display and change the default Java environment.

This script sets link `java-default-runtime` to point at a valid non-conflicting Java environment installed in `/var/lib/jvm/java-${JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION}-${VENDOR_NAME}`. It also creates and updates links in `/usr/bin` for all executable provided by the Java environment set.

Helper script `archlinux-java` provides such functionalities:

```
archlinux-java <COMMAND>

COMMAND:
    status          List installed Java environments and enabled one
    get             Return the short name of the Java environment set as default
    set <JAVA_ENV>    Force <JAVA_ENV> as default
    unset           Unset current default Java environment
    fix             Fix an invalid/broken default Java environment configuration
```

## List compatible Java environments installed

```
% archlinux-java status
```

Example:

```
% archlinux-java status
Available Java environments:  
  java-7-openjdk (default)  
  java-8-openjdk/jre
```

Note the *(default)* denoting that `java-7-openjdk` is currently set as default. Invocation of `java` and other binaries will rely on this Java install. Also note on the previous output that only the *JRE* part of OpenJDK 8 is installed here.

## Change default Java environment

```
% archlinux-java set <JAVA_ENV_NAME>
```

Example:

```
% archlinux-java set java-8-openjdk/jre
```

Note that `archlinux-java` will not let you set an invalid Java environment. In the previous example, [jre8-openjdk](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=jre8-openjdk) is installed but `jdk8-openjdk  is **not** so trying to set`java-8-openjdk` will fail:

```
% archlinux-java set java-8-openjdk
'/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk' is not a valid Java environment path
```

Answer (score 0):

Linux and Java go very well together, but creature comfort when switching between versions could be better.

On my ubuntu installation I now have 3 actively used versions: jdk8, jdk-11 lts and jdk12. I learned that installing by hand gives the best experience overall, because of the complexity added by the debian java switcher scripts.

I am in the habit of starting my IDE (netbeans) via the command line. always. period.
This gives you full control of what JDK to use and what it starts with or opens, project wise.

My solution for fast switching comprises of four parts:

1. Using the environment variable $JAVA_HOME, which is an established standard and is used by e.g. ant and maven.
2. Using a script called J that edits the $PATH environment variable
3. symlinks to the script like ln -sf J J8 (capitals)
4. aliases to make the switching very easy on the typing: j8 for java 8, j11 for 11 etc.

```
#!/bin/bash

## This script assumes that the JAVA_HOME environment variable is set
##   and that the PATH contains ${JAVA_HOME}/bin
## The java variant that is to be put in JAVA_HOME and PATH is determined
## by how what this script is called.
## J8 for Java 8, J11 for Java 11 and J12 for Java 12. It could easily be
## extended to include Java 9 and 10 too, buy at the time of writing I see
## little point because 12 is the current open JDK and 11 the LTS version.
## J8 is in because it is the default for many still.
##
## You typically have (sym) links pointing to this script, so it appears to have different names, changing its meaning.
##
## Usage: eval $(scriptname) e.g. eval $(J12)
## By using  bash aliases, such as alias j8='eval $(J8)' the use of this script will become a feast.


## get this script name
thisname=$(basename $0)
## get the current path setting
OPATH=${PATH}

## Let my name do the choosing
case ${thisname} in
    J8)
    NJAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle;;
    J11)
    NJAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.2;;
    J12)
    NJAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-12;;
    *)
    echo echo call me as 'eval $(J8)', 'eval $(J11)' or 'eval $(J12)'
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

## edit path to use the new java_home
p=$(echo ${OPATH} | sed -e "s@${JAVA_HOME}/bin@${NJAVA_HOME}/bin@")

##
echo export JAVA_HOME=${NJAVA_HOME}
echo export PATH=${p}
```

Then I symlink this file like `ln -sf J J8 ; ln -sf J J11` etc.

The aliases are defined in my ~/.bash_aliases script.

```
alias j10='eval $(J10)'
alias j11='eval $(J11)'
alias j12='eval $(J12)'
```